# How to create birthday workflow using Microsoft flow template?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have one requirement from my client. I have to create one Microsoft flow which will work as a reminder. Whoever have birthday on that specific day he will get birthday message. As i am new in Sharepoint, not getting any ideas how to do that. I am using Sharepoint designer 2013. Any leads will be appriciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Flow is not an option?

Comment: Thanks for responce. I am using Sharepoint 2013. For new Sharepoint mordern experience i need to create that.